# google jQuery UI links not working offline

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

im new to jquery, i have searched for the reason my jquery is not working after adding the `<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>`
I have searched this forum and the web but can,t seem to find the answer, mybe my code is wrong. or maybe is some terminologies that scare me away. But i will be glad if someone helps me.

here is the code:

```
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>JAVASCRIPT TRIAL</title>
<style>
div {
    position:relative;
    top:50px;
    width:200px;
    height:200px;
    border-radius:10px;
    margin:auto;
    background-color:#F00;
    box-shadow:2px;
}
div2 {
    position:relative;
    top:50px;
    width:200px;
    height:200px;
    border-radius:50px;
    margin:auto;
    background-color:#F60;
}
</style>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('div').click(function(){
        $(this).addClass('div');
    });
    $('div').hover(function(){
    $(this).effect('bounce', {times:4}, 1000);
    });
});
</script>
</head>

<body>
<div></div>
</body>
</html>
```

thank you guys in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What do you mean off line? If you not going to have Internet access then you'd be better downloading a version from jquery and having it local.

Answer (score 0):

Google jQuery UI links will never work offline. You should download it in your local system and then have to use it.